# Python Inheritance and Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, inheritance

I am just trying inheritance out for the first time in a Django app and I am running into trouble.

I have two classes, ProjectDetailView and ProjectDetailViewWithLinks that inherits from ProjectDetailView.   I basically want to run a set of functions from the base class (**init** and then **buildContextData).   After this I then want to add to the context data using a function called __buildPrevAndNext and then finalise the get function.   I have attached some code.   The __init** seems to work correctly, but when I get to the super().__buildContextData it keeps going wrong and doesn't go into the base class:

```
class ProjectDetailView(View):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__contextData = None
        self.__intPK = None
        self.__intLangID = None

    def __buildContextData(self, request,  **kwargs):
        '''
        This is used to build the context data that we are going to send to the template.
        I have done it this way because I want to build two versions of the class.   One
        that has a previous/next project link, but another class that does not.   This base
        class does not have the previous/next link.
        '''

        # Get the primary key of the Project and the corresponding MyProject object
        self.__intPK = self.kwargs['pk']
        project = MyProject.objects.get(pk=self.__intPK)

        # get the formatted date
        formatedDate = project.date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

        # Either throw a 404 or get the group id of the training course
        if not project.language:
            raise Http404

        # Store the language id
        self.__intLangID = project.language.id

        # Build the contextData
        self.__contextData = {
            'project': project,
            'formatedDate': formatedDate,
            'language': project.language,
        }


    def get(self, request, **kwargs):

        # Build the context data
        self.__buildContextData(request, **kwargs)

        # Now send the data to the template
        return render(request, 'project_detail.html', context=self.__contextData)

class ProjectDetailViewWithLinks(ProjectDetailView):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def __buildContextData(self, request,  **kwargs):
        super().__buildContextData(request, **kwargs)

    def __buildPrevAndNext(self, request):
        '''
        This should be run after __buildContextData and adds the extra data into the context for displaying
        the previous and next links.
        '''

        # Filter TrainingCourse table to a list containing the same group id of this course
        filtProjects = MyProject.objects.filter(language_id=self.__intLangID)

        # Get the next course from this list and the previous course from this list
        nextProject = filtProjects.filter(pk__gt=self.__intPK)
        if len(nextProject)>0:
            nextProject = nextProject[0]

        prevProject = filtProjects.filter(pk__lt=self.__intPK)
        if len(prevProject)>0:
            prevProject = prevProject[len(prevProject)-1]

        # Add the previous and next to the context
        self.__contextData['next'] = nextProject
        self.__contextData['prev'] = prevProject


    def get(self, request, **kwargs):

        # First, build the context data in a similar manner to the ProjectDetailView class
        self.__buildContextData(request, **kwargs)

        # Next, add the next and prev data onto the context data
        self.__buildPrevAndNext(request)

        # Finally render the template
        return render(request, 'project_detail.html', context=self.__contextData)
```

Could you please explain what I am doing wrong and doesn't even go into the base class function.

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Rename you method to have a single leading underscore:

```
def _buildContextData(self, request,  **kwargs):
```

Double leading underscore triggers [name mangling](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-does-double-underscore-prefix-do-in-Python-variables).

Comment: Thank's for that.   I suppose one way of thinking of it was that I was making the functions and variables private rather than protected.   It was a silly mistake, but thank you for all of your help.